# Rewriter URLs for files in subfolder

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I have a question regarding configuring apache for the following setting:

1. URLs like http://www.example.com/abc.html should point to DOCUMENT_ROOT/abc.html
2. URLs like http://www.example.com/_dev/abc.html should point to DOCUMENT_ROOT/_dev/abc.html
3. URL in HTML files served from DOCUMENT_ROOT/_dev should be rewritten from "/abc.html" to "/_dev/abc.html" automatically

Comment: 1 or 2 don't require any rewrite, happens automatically. And 3 is confusing since `DOCUMENT_ROOT/_dev/abc.html` is same as `/_dev/abc.html` in URL.

Comment: @anubhava's comment is true. Also, i don't understand your third point

Comment: For example I have a file DOCUMENT_ROOT/index.html which contains a link to "/about.html". Apache should rewrite this link to "/_dev/about.html"

Comment: So you want `/about.html` rewritten as `/_dev/about.html`? Is this rewriting specific to `about.html` only or should affect all `*.html` files.

Comment: It should affect all html files and subfolders as "css/" and "js/"

Comment: But it will affect `/index.html` also to be `/_dev/index.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# if not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# if URI is not starting with /_dev/ then rewrite to /_dev/<uri>
RewriteRule ^((?!_dev/).*)$ /_dev/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: In the end this works but does not solve my problem.

Comment: I want to rewrite the urls in /_dev/abc.html such that the deliverd index.html in the browser has urls modified from /abc.html to /_dev/abc.html

Comment: If I understand you correct you want to show `/abc.html` in browser but want to show content from `/_dev/abc.html` isn't it?

Comment: now, the browser still shows "/_dev/abc.html", but the absolute links in abc.html like "/about.html" are tranformed  to "/_dev/about.html". I create the site below "/_dev" with a generator which assumes that the created html is served from documentroot, but I want to shift it to a subfolder without modifying the generated html myself.

Comment: This .htaccess is to be placed in `DocumentRoot` (1 level above `_dev`). And do you want `/_dev/abc.html` to become `/abc.html` in browser URL bar?

Comment: I already put it to `DocumentRoot` and the link in the URL bar should stay unmodified as `/_dev/abc.html`. Meanwhile I have a shell script using `sed` to run over all `.html` files in  `_dev/` which modifies links starting with `/` by prepending `/_dev`.

Comment: So I'm confused what's not working, need some details here. Are you getting 404? What URL do you see in browser when you get 404? Does your .htaccess have more rules or just this rule?

Comment: Well the existing page `/abc.html` is overridden by `/_dev/abc.html`